# Firebase ref.on('value') continuously calls, even when there is no change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using an event listener to check for changes to my realtime database.

```
  const [chats, setChats] = useState({});
  const ref = db.ref(`users/${sender}/chat/`);
  ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    setChats(data);
  });
```

I keep getting too many re-renders. The Firebase docs say that it's only supposed to update when there's a change to the children. Did I do something wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: That seems unexpected, but I don't see anything in the code you shared that would explain it. Is there anyway you can set up a minimal reproduction on a site like jsbin or stackblitz, so that I can have a look at it?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely that the code in your question runs for each render, changes the state and thus, re-renders. Ala infinite loop

Try using a [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Bonus points for removing the listener in the [cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)

```js
const [chats, setChats] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  const ref = db.ref(`users/${sender}/chat/`);

  // value listener function
  const onValue = (snapshot) => {
    setChats(snapshot.val());
  };

  // register listener
  ref.on("value", onValue);

  // return a cleanup function to remove the listener
  return () => ref.off("value", onValue);
}, [sender]);
```

---

Using the V9 SDK looks a little different. The `onValue()` [listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events) returns its own [unsubscribe](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#unsubscribe) function

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const chatRef = ref(db, `users/${sender}/chat/`);

  // return the unsubscribe function
  return onValue(chatRef, (snapshot) => {
    setChats(snapshot.val());
  });
}, [sender]);
```