# What is the correct way to use Firebase onValue() method with React useState()?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some code to pull user data from my Firebase Realtime Database. I use the onValue method to update my React state when this data changes.

```
  const [onlineUsersStatus, setOnlineUsersStatus] = useState([])
  const usersRef = ref(database, 'users')
  onValue(usersRef, (snapshot) => {
    const tmpArray = []
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot, index) => {
      tmpArray[childSnapshot.key] = childSnapshot.val()
    })
    setOnlineUsersStatus(tmpArray)
  })
```

For some reason, this causes an infinite loop. Without using the setOnlineUsersStatus(), onValue() runs once as expected. I imagine it is something related to the setOnlineUsersStatus() method causing a re-render, which runs the initial onValue() to run "once" again.

What is the correct way to write this so I can update the state using onValue(), but not have the re-render causing my onValue() to run again?

I've tried using the useEffect() method outlined [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67831073/2338587) with no luck. I can't even seem to use the .on() and .off() methods. I'm definitely missing something.

EDIT: Using the method from the above updated question, I've created the following that still causes too many re-renders.

```
  const [onlineUsersStatus, setOnlineUsersStatus] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = ref(database, 'users')
    return onValue(usersRef, (snapshot) => {
      const users = []
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        users.push({
          key: child.key,
          ...child.val()
        })
      })
      setOnlineUsersStatus(users)
    })
  }, [])
```

EDIT 2: The above fix does in fact work. In my case I have additional online state management code in my component that is causing further re-renders.

```
  // Online state management
  const myConnectionsRef = ref(database, 'users/' + auth.currentUser.uid + '/connections')
  const lastOnlineRef = ref(database, 'users/' + auth.currentUser.uid + '/lastOnline')
  const connectedRef = ref(database, '.info/connected')
  onValue(connectedRef, (snap) => {
    if (snap.val() === true) {
      const con = push(myConnectionsRef)
      onDisconnect(con).remove()
      set(con, true)
      onDisconnect(lastOnlineRef).set(serverTimestamp())
    }
  })
```

Comment: `childSnapshot.key` isn't a valid array index. Are you sure you're after an array and not an object?

Comment: _"I can't even seem to use the .on() and .off() methods"_... the Realtime Database documentation around that is sorely lacking for v9. I had to dig into the reference docs

Comment: Hi, I wrote the answer to that linked question and have updated it for Firebase SDK v9 which should help

Comment: @Phil thanks for editing your original response, I've tried to implement it as you've outlined and it still results in the loop. I've edited my attempt into the question, is there anything I've missed?

Comment: I'll whip up a reproduction in CodeSandbox but I suspect the issue might be with another part of your code. What are you doing with the `onlineUsersStatus` array?

Comment: Seems to work fine here ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/async-field-r1psi5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: My apologies for the time wasting, it seems my online state management is another cause of my re-renders (edited in my question). Your answer does stop the re-renders for that section.